# Why does a question that was closed as a dupe remain closed after the dupe is deleted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

It's kind of a bummer that [this question was closed as a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570917) for 4 reasons:

1. The duplicate question was created as a snarky (yet funny) joke after the fact.
2. The duplicate question has since been deleted.
3. The question covers an actual unix shell usage question.
4. The question had a pretty funny string of star wars quotes paraphrased to refer to unix shell usage.

Comment: Wait... Isn't that a SU question?

Comment: That's no SU question. It's a space station.

Comment: SU? I'm not going to SU, I've gotta get *home*, it's late, I'm in for it as it is!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a question that was closed as a dupe remain closed after the dupe is deleted?

Because nobody updates it. I don't think they are cross-referenced so that this update can be done automatically...just flag it for moderator attention with the hint that the linked question is now gone.

Also, the close process is a democratic process, so you have to ask the five close-voters why they have voted for it.

Comment: they probably voted to close it because they're trek fans!